# Unable to build blender from source getting error: function does not return NSString

Tags: blender

I'm trying to build blender from source in mac.
Mac version - 12.5.1
xCode - installed.

I ran **make** command and it failed with and error.

update - looks like re running is progressing. not sure how.

Comment: please provide more details (version you’re trying to compile, log of your console with the commands used, error messages…)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.